# Looking for a JQuery plug-in similar to Accordion, but that allows multiple sections open at once

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking to have a UI element similar to that offered by the JQUERY Accordion plug-in, but allowing the user to keep multiple sections open at once.

The documentation has the following to say, and suggests an alternate approach with a code snippet (see below). That is great and all, and the code they provide basically works, but I find myself recreating a lot of things built into the plugin like switching out the classes and applying the themes manually in the XHTML.

**My Questions:**

1. Before I get too far along the manual route, does anyone know of a similar plug-in, or mod to this one to allow multiple panels to be open at once?
2. Is there a another common name for an accordion-like control that allows multiple open panels that I could use to Google for other options?

Here is the part I referenced earlier from the documentation, if it matters.

> **NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion**
>
> An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are looking for a widget that allows more than one content panel to be open, don't use this. Usually it can be written with a few lines of jQuery instead, something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});

Or animated:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions, but I finally found something on my own that does exactly what I was looking for. I'm adding it as an answer for anyone else who needs something similar.

**The Solution**
Using the code and sample XHTML [here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/105888/) you can extend the [JQuery Accordion plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion) to have multiple panels open at once and keep the theming and other functionality provided by the plug-in without recreating the styles.

See the site linked above for a complete example, but here is the meat of the code needed to make the accordion control allow multiple panels to be open. Use the same HTML to define the headers and content as described in the plug-in documentation

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").addClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons")
        .find("h3")
            .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
            .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>')
            .click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active").toggleClass("ui-state-active")
                    .toggleClass("ui-state-default").toggleClass("ui-corner-bottom")
                .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s")
                .end().next().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active").toggle();
                return false;
            })
            .next().addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom").hide();
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @JohnFx, I need same functionality but on post back I want to maintain open/close state of sections. Any help thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I have done a jQuery plugin that has the same look of jQuery UI Accordion and can keep all tabs\sections open

you can find it here

http://anasnakawa.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/jquery-ui-multi-open-accordion/

works with the same markup

```
<div id="multiOpenAccordion">
        <h3><a href="#">tab 1</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <h3><a href="#">tab 2</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(function(){
        $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiAccordion();
       // you can use a number or an array with active option to specify which tabs to be opened by default:
       $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiAccordion({ active: 1 });
       // OR
       $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiAccordion({ active: [1, 2, 3] });

       $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiAccordion({ active: false }); // no opened tabs
});
```

UPDATE:
the plugin has been updated to support default active tabs option

Comment: You don't need a plugin for this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/10237915/222564

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use 1 accordion per section, as Matthew Brown also said.

```
$( "#accordion1" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });
$( "#accordion2" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });
$( "#accordion3" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed a few things presumably for 1.8.5.

Moving the toggle fixed a state change problem (click show, click no hide, click hide, click show, click hide...)
Classes somewhat mismatched jquery's template and rendering suffered

```
    $(".colapse").addClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons")
  .find("h3")       
          .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-corner-all ui-state-default")
          .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>')
          .click(function() {
              $j(this).toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active").toggleClass("ui-corner-all").toggleClass("ui-corner-top").toggleClass("ui-state-active")
                          .toggleClass("ui-state-default")
                  .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s")
                  .end().next().toggle().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active");
              return false;
          })
          .next().addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified some code I had found online last week looking for a similar solution.  This assumes that each accordion is a nested unordered list.  To get this working you must have **unique IDs** for each of your accordions.  Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="uniqueAccordion1" class="menu">
    <li class="noaccordion">
        <a href="#">Top Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Top Level 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    // initialize admin menu
    loadNav();
});
function loadNav() {
    // initially show opened
    $.each($('ul.menu'), function(){
        $('#' + this.id + ' .expandfirst ul:first').show();
    });

    // watch for click
    $('ul.menu li > a').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $parent = $this.parent();
        if ($parent.hasClass('noaccordion')) {
            return false;
        }
        var $checkElement = $this.next();
        if ($checkElement.is('ul')) {
            $checkElement.slideToggle('fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

You will need your own CSS to support this but it allows for any number of accordions and also allows you to disable a particular section from being closed (if, for instance, you use this for navigation) by adding the class **noaccordion** to a main level LI tag.  Lastly, you may add a class **expandfirst** to a main level LI to auto open the accordion for the matching element(s) on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Edited *anasnakawa* code for those **who don't need jQuery UI Accordion styling** and wants to keep the code simple. *(hope you'll find it useful)*

HTML:

```
<div id="multiOpenAccordion">
        <h3>tab 1</h3>
        <div>A lot of text</div>
        <h3>tab 2</h3>
        <div>A lot of thex 2</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
        $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiAccordion();
});
```

**Changed code:**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        multiAccordion: function(options) {
            var defaults = {};
            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $h3 = $this.children('h3');
                var $div = $this.children('div');

                $h3.click(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $div = $this.next();

                    if ($this.hasClass('closed')) {
                        $this.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
                        $div.slideDown('fast');
                    } else {
                        $this.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
                        $div.slideUp('fast');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

***Edit:***
If you use Malihu custom scrollbar then there may be problems with IE. IE drops error saying

> Invalid argument, Line xx, character xxx

I removed this code from Malihu scrollbar (which is responsible about scrolling content which is more than 1000px glitch) - It helped.

```
$.fx.prototype.cur = function(){
    if ( this.elem[this.prop] != null && (!this.elem.style || this.elem.style[this.prop] == null) ) {
      return this.elem[ this.prop ];
    }
    var r = parseFloat( jQuery.css( this.elem, this.prop ) );
    return typeof r == 'undefined' ? 0 : r;
}
```

This gave me real headache

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet fixes the corner problem (the header bottom corner should disappear when expanding and vice visa)

```
$("#accordion").addClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons")
.find("h3")
        .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-corner-bottom ui-corner-top ui-state-default")
        .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
        .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>')
        .click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active").toggleClass("ui-state-active")
                .toggleClass("ui-state-default").toggleClass("ui-corner-bottom")
                .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s")
                .end().next().slideToggle().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active");
            return false;
        })
        .next().addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="accordion">
        <li id="one" class="files">
            <a href="#one">Admin Video</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminvideo/addvideo"><em>01</em>Add video</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminvideo"><em>02</em>List Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminvideo/categorys"><em>03</em>Video Categories</a></li>                 
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="two" class="mail">
            <a  href="#two">Users</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/admin/listsubs"><em>01</em>Subscribers List</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>"><em>02</em>User Video Suggestion</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


        <li id="three" class="cloud">
            <a class="active" href="#three">Background Image options</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminsettings"><em>01</em>Add</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/adminsettings/listbgs"><em>02</em>List</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

$(document).ready(function() {


    var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
        accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');
    $.each($(".accordion > li > a"), function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'active')
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }           
    });



    // Open the first tab on load

    //accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

    // Click function

    accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

        // Disable header links

        event.preventDefault();

        // Show and hide the tabs on click

        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            accordion_head.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

hopes it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use multiple accordion instances (1 accordion per section).  I tried using JohnFx's solution above but that created styling issues that I did not have with the default accordion.  When I split my 2 section single accordion into two separate accordions I was able to keep the styling just fine.  In addition, you don't have to deal with the inner css and html implementation of the accordion.