# jquery ui accordion - multiple accordions expand/collapse all - style issues

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm attempting to create an accordion where I can expand/collapse all sections with a single click.  I also need the ability for the user to open and close the sections having 0-n sections open at a time.  Using several of the discussions here on stackoverflow and on jquery forums, here's the solution i've come up with:
I've implemented each section as it's own accordion, where each is set to collapsible = true.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Accordion Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_templates/css/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css"  type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_templates/css/jquery.ui.accordion.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

<body>
        <a onClick="expandAll()">Expand All</a>
        <br>
        <a onClick="collapseAll()">Collapse All</a>
            <div id="accordion1" class="accord">
            <h5><a href="#">section 1</a></h5>
            <div>
                    section 1 text  
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- orders section -->
            <div id="accordion2" class="accord">
            <h5><a href="#">section 2</a></h5>
            <div>
                    section 2 text  
            </div>
            </div>

            <!--  section 3 -->
            <div id="accordion3" class="accord">
            <h5><a href="#">section 3</a></h5>
            <div>
                    section 3 text  
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- section 4 -->
            <div id="accordion4">
            <h5><a href="#">section 4</a></h5>
            <div>
                    section 4 text                  
            </div>
            </div>


</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#accordion1').accordion({
        header: 'h5',
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#accordion2').accordion({
        header: 'h5',
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#accordion3').accordion({
        header: 'h5',
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#accordion4').accordion({
        header: 'h5',
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

})

function expandAll() {
    alert("calling expandAll");
    $("#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3, #accordion4")
        .filter(":not(:has(.ui-state-active))")
        .accordion("activate", 0);
}

function collapseAll() {
    alert("calling collapseAll");
    $("#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3, #accordion4")
        .filter(":has(.ui-state-active)")
        .accordion("activate", -1);
}

</script>
```

The problem I'm running into, is when I click the header of an open section, the section is collapsed as expected, but the header still have the "ui-state-focus" class, until I click elsewhere on the page.  So what I see in the ui is the header of section just closed has the same background color as my hover effect, until I click elsewhere, and it shifts to the 'default, not focused' color.

In addition, when I use the Collapse All link, all looks great in Firefox.  In IE, the last section header has the same hover-focus coloring.

Any suggestions?  Do I somehow need to force the accordion to lose focus when it is closed?  How would I accomplish that?

Comment: This is not solution for one accordion. In sample multiple accordions are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After attempting to over-ride my jquery-ui styles on the page, and attempting to hack the accordion javascript to remove the ui-state-focus class, a simple solution came to light.

Because my page is displaying the expected behavior when I click else where on the page, I used blur() to lose focus.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // forces lose focus when accordion section closed. IE and FF.
    $(".ui-accordion-header").click(function(){
          $(this).blur();
        });

})
```

To fix the collapse all issue in IE, I added 1 line to my collapseAll() method.

```
function collapseAll() {
    alert("calling collapseAll");
    $("#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3, #accordion4")
        .filter(":has(.ui-state-active)")
        .accordion("activate", -1);
    $(".ui-accordion-header").blur();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution to implement accordion with all open panels. Panels are static and can't be closed.

Do not initialize accordion div with accordion widget!

```
$("#accordion").addClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
  .find('h3')
  .addClass("current ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top")
  .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>')
  .next().addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active");
```

Answer (score 2):

this is my answer~ hope its help

for multiple open you can do like this by using existing jquery UI just add in a options beforeActivate:

my code below:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
             // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
            if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
             // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
            } else {
                var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
            }
             // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
            var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

             // Toggle the panel's header
            currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

            // Toggle the panel's icon
            currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);

             // Toggle the panel's content
            currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)    
            if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp('fast'); }  else { currContent.slideDown('fast'); }

            return false; // Cancels the default action
        }
    });
```

refer from :[jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open)

and the function collapse and expand

```
function accordion_expand_all()
{
  var sections = $('#accordion').find("h3");
  sections.each(function(index, section){
    if ($(section).hasClass('ui-state-default') && !$(section).hasClass('accordion-header-active')) {
      $(section).click();
    }
  });

}

function accordion_collapse_all()
{
  var sections = $('#accordion').find("h3");
  sections.each(function(index, section){
    if ($(section).hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
      $(section).click();
    }
  });
}
```

that's it..

Comment: Very nice solution! Like it! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this small, lightweight plugin.

It will have few options available which we can modify as per our requirement.

**URL:** http://accordion-cd.blogspot.com/