# jQueryUI accordion - Keep sections open

Tags: jquery, accordion

Can anyone show me how I make the accordion stay open eg if I click 3 sections all 3 remain open?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion1" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
```

Comment: hi @Zabs, did you find a solution for this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [jQuery UI documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion):

> **NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion**
>
> An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time, and it > takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are looking for a widget that allows more than one > content panel to be open, don't use this. Usually it can be written with a few lines of > jQuery instead, something like this:

Comment: can you give any alternate idea? I need @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann,

Answer (score 0):

Klaus Byskov Pedersen says the right thing 

 here is your solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('.head').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest('li').find('.content').slideToggle(); 
    }); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-accordion-tutorial)