# Working with jQuery UI “Accordion and Droppable” Part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Working with same Problem: [Working with jQuery UI "Accordion and Droppable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165336/working-with-jquery-ui-accordion-and-droppable)

If I want to pick an item then drop it into the accordion(`<h3>`), then append it to the `<ul>`.

For example, drag "Item 1" to "B", then append "Item 1" to the yellow list.

How could I modify the program?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({connectWith: '.connectedSortable'}).disableSelection();

    var $tabs = $( "#tabs" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        header: "> div > h3",
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#maps").width( $("#tabsMap").innerWidth() - $("#mapList").width() - 34 );
        },
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#maps").width( $("#tabsMap").innerWidth() - $("#mapList").width() - 32 );
        }
    }).sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjvWN/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make the `<h3>` a droppable target and then on the "drop" event append the target item to the corresponding `<ul>`.

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/