# maccordion, how to expand multiple divs with click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is what I'm looking to do.  I'm using Accordion w/ Jquery.  On a page, I have multiple products that are hidden and I am searching for a tool to expand all the divs with one click.  I read that maccordion would be helpful, but I'm not seeing an example or know how to navigate the help doc well enough to accomplish this.

```
<div class="maccordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>

    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>

    <h3><a href="#">Third header</a></h3>
    <div>Third content</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){


        $( ".maccordion" ).maccordion( { active: false } );

        $( ".maccordion" ).maccordion( "option", "active", [-1] );

    });
</script>
```

What I would like to do is click on the First header and have the second and third expand.  The first header would just be a "click here to expand all" option.

Do you know how I would do that with maccordion?  What would I put inside the script function?

I found another script that worked great, Multiple Accordion Open, but I am using JQuery 1.8.3 and JQuery UI 1.10 and that was not supported in these versions.

thanks

Comment: What is **"maccordion"**..? Usually an **accordion** widget closes the opened them when another one is clicked... If you want to open everything all together, You're not looking for an *accordion* i guess...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your description, you're not actually looking for an accordion functionality. For toggling a set of content all together, you can combine a bit of custom  CSS and jQuery as shown below:

```js
$("#toggleAll").click(function(){
  $(".maccordion").find("h3+div").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
h3 + div{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="toggleAll">Expand All</a>
<div class="maccordion">
  <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
  <div>First content</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
  <div>Second content</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Third header</a></h3>
  <div>Third content</div>
</div>
```

---

However, If you must use jquery-ui accordion, then you might find helpful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15702444/2333214)