# Custom accordion content divs all share same size, no idea why

Tags: jquery

I'm building a website and found this custom accordion build with jQuery (basically, I want to have multiple containers open at the same time), and now I figured out that regardless of their content, all containers share the same size (so if I have content in the top container, all 3 will have a big height). What am I missing, and how do I get every container to scale to it's content? thanks for the help

Since the fiddle isn't displaying correctly because of the local jQuery-UI files I've uploaded the whole thing [here](http://topdeckandwreck.com/stackOverflow/Draft%20Import%20mySQL/).

```js
$('#accordion').accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: 1,
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
    // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
    if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
      var currHeader = ui.newHeader;
      var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
      // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
    } else {
      var currHeader = ui.oldHeader;
      var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
    }
    // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
    var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

    // Toggle the panel's header
    currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top', !isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected', ((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

    // Toggle the panel's icon
    currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s', !isPanelSelected);

    // Toggle the panel's content
    currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active', !isPanelSelected)
    if (isPanelSelected) {
      currContent.slideUp();
    } else {
      currContent.slideDown();
    }

    return false; // Cancels the default action
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).tooltip();
  $(".btn").button();
  $("#dialog").dialog();
  $("#dialog").dialog("close");
  $("#check1").button();
  $("#check2").button();
});

$("#loadFile").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
})
```

```css
#cardbox,
#previewbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cardbox {
  width: 80%;
}
#previewbox {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3 title="This is where the cards you draft from will appear when the draft file is loaded.">Cards</h3>
    <div>
      <div id="cardbox">BLAH</div>
      <div id="previewbox">BLAH</div>
    </div>
    <h3>Control Box</h3>
    <div>
      <form id="controlbox">Draft number:
        <input type="text" placeholder="#" title="In case you are uploading a draft from file, leave this field blank. Otherwise please input your draft number and click the search button.">
        <input type="submit" value="Search for Draft" class="btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="loadFile">Load from file</button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Other Options:
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
        <label for="check1">Show Previous Picks</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check2">
        <label for="check2">Use Timer</label>
      </form>
    </div>
    <h3 title="This is where the cards you pick will appear.">Picks Log</h3>
    <div>This is where your picks will be displayed</div>
  </div>
  <div id="dialog" title="Upload Draft Log" class="filePrompt">
    <form>Click the browse button in order to select the log file on your hard-drive.
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="file" id="draftLogInput">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/import.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the panels is controlled by the accordion's [`heightStyle`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle) property, which has three possible values:

> "auto": All panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel.
>
> "fill": Expand to the available height based on the accordion's parent height.
>
> "content": Each panel will be only as tall as its content.

The default value is `auto`, so if this property is not explicitly passed to the accordion, the height of all panels would indeed be the same, as you describe. The behavior you seem to be after can be achieved by explicitly passing `heightStyle: 'content'`.

For example,

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
     collapsible: true,
     active: 1,
     heightStyle: 'content',
     beforeActivate: function() {/*...*/}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some stylesheet issues, everything looked fine in the snippet view below. But you might try setting the padding on the cardbox and preview to 0. And their margins to auto.

Also might want to try vertical align around those in a div set to middle or top.

A radical solution is to replace your two div elements with td elements or spans. As divs misbehave when put side by side unless you fiddle with their style.

Comment: this is the first thing I thought, probably some jQuery-UI css fighting with the customized javascript, so I tried changing the #accordion onto something else, and the results were the same. The only css I added is the one posted, everything else is from the jQuery-UI. The snippet is weird, because jQuery ui isn't loaded, I'm loading it from local files. It's kinda hard to recreate what I'm talking about I guess...

Comment: [ http://topdeckandwreck.com/stackOverflow/Draft%20Import%20mySQL/ ] Here's how the whole thing looks. The tabs (Cards, Control Box, Picks Log) are all the same height when expanded, instead of adjusting to their content

Comment: tried replacing the divs with a table, same thing happens, all three panels always have the same size.