# jQuery Accordion - Open multiple panels at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

My jQuery script is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#accordions-727.accordions").accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: "false", 
        event: "click",
        heightStyle: "content",
    })
})
```

So when I open the first tab and leave it open, and then when I open the second tab the first one closes.How can I open multiple panels at once?

I tried what was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702444/jquery-ui-accordion-open-multiple-panels-at-once) but none seems to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open)

Comment: could you please check  the version of jquery between [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702444/jquery-ui-accordion-open-multiple-panels-at-once) and your code

Comment: My version is 1.9.2 @nivendha

Answer (score 0):

Would turning it into multiple accordions work Ok for your case?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="./jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
        $(".myaccordion" ).each(function( index ) {$(this).accordion({collapsible:true});});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myaccordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div><p>one</p></div>
</div>
<div class="myaccordion">   
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div><p>two</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```