# how to keep open another div in accordian using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is the link of my website I'm working on 
http://shopping.netsuite.com/s.nl/c.3727898/it.A/id.23/.f

when i click on product description it opens and when i click on product specification, product description gets close. I want to keep open that product description tag open when i click on product specification and also when click on third section top two must remain open how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `collapsible` option to true: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: It's working but when i refresh the page by default all the section keeps open. i want to make 1st section active and after that collapse all should work

Answer (score 0):

It's not anymore an accordion if you want multiple sections opened. If you are looking to just expand-collapse the sections you can achieve this with just jQuery.

html:

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>Some text...</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>Some text...</div>
<h3>Section 3</h3>
<div>Some text...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('h3').click(function() {
   $(this).next('div').slideToggle('slow');   
})
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/9Vscz/1/)

Comment: hmm. which one have you tried, something else might have gone wrong and we cant just look it up in your actual site especially if you are working with jQuery UI. I found a similar question posted there are several solutions in here that might help you out. [jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open)