# jQuery UI Accordion open multiple tabs on start

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I open multiple tabs on start in accordion? Like this way

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

```js
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 3 );
```

or like this?

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  active: 1
  active: 2
});
```

Comment: You might find a hint here [jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open)

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use multiAccordion and it goes like this:
    // this will make the second tab by default opened (index starts from 0)
    $('.selector').multiAccordion({active: 1 }); 

    // [ OR ]
    // supports multiple tabs to be opened by default
    $('.selector').multiAccordion({active: [1, 2, 3] }); 

   // you can also set active:false if you don't want any tab to be opened by default
   $('.selector').multiAccordion({active: false });

   // show all tabs
   $('.selector').multiAccordion({active: 'all' });

   // hide all tabs
   $('.selector').multiAccordion({active: 'none' });

   // you can set the options as any jQuery UI plugin using option method
   $('.selector').multiAccordion('option', 'active', 'all');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**JS**

```
 $("#accordion > div").accordion({ header: "h2", collapsible: true });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <h2><a href="#">First</a></h2>
        <div>First Secton of hello world.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="#">Second</a></h2>
        <div>Second Secton of hello world.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="#">Third</a></h2>
        <div>Third Secton of hello world.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="#">Fourth</a></h2>
        <div>Forth Secton of hello world.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example in **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/df8kewfj/)**