# Accordion Toggle Arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to work out how I can reset my toggle arrows when opening another accordion panel when one is already open. I have managed to toggle it on the open and close of one panel - but leaving it open and opening another panel has me stumped....

View the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gaLvuac/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="accord-header">
   <img class="arrow-img rotate" src="img.jpg" />
   <h3>Title</h3>
</div>

<div class="accord-content">
   <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {

        $(this).children("img").toggleClass('rotate2');


      if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
        $(this).next("div").slideUp("normal");


      } else {
        $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: JQ accordions only have one section open at a time (I believe)...otherwise they aren't accordions.See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the actual img with class `rotate2` and then remove it, just add this line:

> $('.rotate2').removeClass('rotate2');

```
$(".accordion .accord-header").click(function () {
    $('.rotate2').removeClass('rotate2');
    $(this).find("img").toggleClass('rotate2');
    if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next("div").slideUp("normal");
    } else {
        $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
    }
});
```

#### [DemoFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gaLvuac/1/)

---

**Edit**

Solved the problem when you try to open/close each panel and doesn't change the arrow on the element itself. You can exclude the actual `img`:

```
var im = $(this).find('img');
$('.rotate2').not(im).removeClass('rotate2');
im.toggleClass('rotate2');
```

#### [AnotherDemoFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gaLvuac/3/)

Comment: This is almost there. It just needs to toggle the arrow when you open and close one accordion panel.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {
          $(".accordion .accord-header").children("img").removeClass('rotate2');
          $(this).children("img").toggleClass('rotate2');

          if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
              $(this).next("div").slideUp("normal");
          } else {
              $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
              $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
          }
    });
});
```

You should remove all `rotate2` classes before add class for current element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had some stray code after the else:

```
        $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
```

This slides all of the content up, not just the next. Remove it.

See [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/n9pqzLbd/2/)