# How to make First accordion tab opened by default?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the first tab in this accordion to be opened by default.

Here is the code on cssdeck : http://cssdeck.com/labs/5jlzqlt6

Comment: Add the relevant code _within_ your question.

Comment: your implementation works based on `:target` selector i.e. the hash in the url. So, if you want the first one to be opened, your url should contain `#one` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrqcqv9e/1/)**

add this to your css

```
#accordion ul li:first-child div { 
    display:block;
    border-top:3px solid #FFCDCD;
}
```

also i made a jq ( in a hurry ) to make the accordion work better

code :

```
$("#accordion ul li").each(function(){
var trigger= $(this).find('a')
var siblings = $(this).siblings()
var acc_text = $(this).find('.accordion')
    $(trigger).click(function(){
    var visible_text = siblings.find('.accordion').filter(":visible")
    $(acc_text).slideToggle()
    $(visible_text).slideUp()
    });
});
```

EDIT : if i got it right. you want to be able to have all tabs opened in the same time . see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrqcqv9e/3/)**

code :

```
$("#accordion ul li").each(function(){
var trigger= $(this).find('a')
var acc_text = $(this).find('.accordion')
    $(trigger).click(function(){

        $(acc_text).slideToggle()

    });
});
```

or do you want when you click eg on " example two " all 3 tabs to open at once?. that's strange :) why would you want to do that ?

Snippet

```js
$("#accordion ul li").each(function(){
    var trigger= $(this).find('a')
    var acc_text = $(this).find('.accordion')
    $(trigger).click(function(){
      
        $(acc_text).slideToggle()
  
    });
});
```

```css
body{
background:#d0d0d5;
}


/*  Basic stucture
=====================*/
#accordion{margin:100px auto;width:400px;}
#accordion ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.accordion{display:none;}
.accordion:target{display:block;}
#accordion ul li a{text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:10px;}
.accordion{padding:4px;}





/*  Colors 
====================*/
#accordion ul{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 10px #BDBDBD;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 10px #BDBDBD;
        box-shadow:0 4px 10px #BDBDBD;
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
}
#accordion ul li a{
background:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #E0E0E0;
color:#999;
}
.accordion{
background:#fdfdfd;
color:#999;
}
.accordion:target{
border-top:3px solid #FFCDCD;
}

#accordion ul li:first-child div { 
display:block;
border-top:3px solid #FFCDCD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#one">Example one</a>
      <div id="one" class="accordion">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#two">Example two</a>
      <div id="two" class="accordion">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
      </div>
    </li>    
    <li>
      <a href="#three">Example three</a>
      <div id="three" class="accordion">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfect, however I was also trying to also make all the tabs appear at once when they are clicked instead of what the j-query does which is only one tab appears ( which is the latest tab clicked ). Would you help me with that also?

Comment: Well i think i've answered your initial question ( and more ). Start by trying to edit the js i wrote for you...and post whatever solution you come up with. And then i will help you. Until then...the question you initially asked....is answered

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really appreciate it. I tried searching already here on stack for an answer for that and I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open    <br/>   but I don not really know Javascript well and tried editing yours with the answer I found; so it would be great if you could help me. Aside from that your answer is very appreciated as you mentioned " i've answered your initial question ( and more )" .

Comment: edited my answer . hope i understood what you wanted

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using bootstrap, you can skip all this convoluted stuff simply by adding one word after the collapse class for the accordion section you want expanded by default:

in

```
class="collapse in"
```

Wow that was easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `jQuery` by triggering the click event.

```
$(function(){
    $('#accordion ul li a').eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution no. 3 worked for me. Thank you. If you are using bootstrap accordion and want that one of the accordion should be opened for the first time so add `class="in"`.

Example:

```
<div class="in"
     data-toggle="collapse"
     data-parent="#amway-global-accordion"
     data-target="#ourCompanyOne"
     aria-expanded="true"
     aria-controls="ourCompanyOne">
</div>
```