# Auto extending accordion during searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make search function to allow user to search in accordion. I am able to make it, but I want it to auto extend when user inputs text. [Here is what I got](https://jsfiddle.net/yo967rfr/7/)

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis == ""){
        $('.source > li').show();           
    } else {
        $('.source > li').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
   };
});
```

So is it possible to extend an accordion during search?

Comment: but which one will you open if it is matching in many/all? if you open more than one the accordion may not be the best display option. You should do an autocomplete-like searchable field with matching items displayed like dropdown.

Comment: @antoni in my case my accordion is in alphabetical order, so for me it will match only in one. so it is ok for me, fiddle just an example, I will change it to show how mine looks like

Comment: @antoni you can check updated fiddle, as you can see it is sorted in alphabetical order, so I think whatever input is it should extend one tab only

Comment: What I mean is if you type `c` only, u will have to open accordion A and C. Before you update your code with `slideToggle()` in your keyup event, you should think about a better way to display the matches as it should show each match at any keyup. ;) Now if you do so in accordion and just open all while searching it doesn't make good UI and accordion is useless

Comment: I just found this post which also gives the same idea as mine - you might find it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3479475/2012407

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what actually you trying to do with your code ? or your plan to do ?

anyway you try to display `.source > li` list item after search that not gonna work simply like that. Because first you have to display your accordion then try to show your list. replace your `keyup()` function like this

```
$('#box').on('keyup', function () {
   // $('.ui-accordion-content').hide();
    var valThis = $(this).val();

    if(valThis == ""){
      $('.ui-accordion-content').hide(); 
    } else {
      $('.item').each(function () {
          var currentLiText = $(this).find('p').text().toLowerCase(),
          showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(valThis) !== -1;
          $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);
          $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').show();
      });

      $('.ui-accordion-content').each(function () {
        if($(this).children('.source').children(':visible').length == 0) {
           $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
});
```

and full example with your code https://jsfiddle.net/05e1smbs/

***Note*** I changed little-bit on `<li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span><p>Aaron</p></li>` li markup for get the text of the `li`. See here https://jsfiddle.net/05e1smbs/