# Accordion that doesn't collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Below is my accordion JS, I basically want it so it doesn't collapse the active question when another one is clicked. I only want it to collapse when clicked.

```
//accordion
    $(".accordion").accordion({

        heightStyle: 'content',
        icons: {"header": "template-arrow-circle-right", "activeHeader": "template-arrow-circle-down"},
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
```

Comment: Its better to post also post your html code here. It's hard to imagine your problem

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open