# jQuery slide - dont close the previous accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Guys this is a jQuery accordion, where the previous accordion(tab) closes off when you open a new one. For example, when you open the first tab, and then you open the second tab, the first one closes off. Basically, when you open a tab, the other one closes off. How do i prevent the previous one from closing off? The tab should close only when the user clicks on it again.

Here's the jQuery -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var open = $('.openx'),
        a = $('ul').find('a');

    console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

    open.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            speed = 500;
        if ($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
            $this.removeClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideUp(speed);
        }
        else if (a.hasClass('active') === false) {
            $this.addClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideDown(speed);
        } else {
            a.removeClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideUp(speed);
            $this.addClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
        }

    });       
});
```

The accordion is in `ul` `li` format, with `a` tag having the class `openx`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open)

Comment: @zero01alpha - check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply commenting out the below line will work. as it is the one which closes all items.

```
 a.removeClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideUp(speed);
```