# Jquery Accordions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using following function to show my accordions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".accordion h3:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion div:not(:first)").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("fast")
        .siblings("div:visible").slideDown("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
    });

});
</script>
```

so first accordion is open on page load then when i click on any other accordion one which is already open stays open and the other one opens also, previous one only closes when i click on it. What i would like to achieve is closing previous accordion when clicking on next one. Can anybody help me with restructuring that function.
Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081919/how-to-properly-sort-multiple-accordions-with-jquery/5113905#5113905 As this answer says (and the official docs http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) ... Accordions should not be used if you want multiple sections open at the same time.

Comment: Hi James 
Thanks for prompt respond i guess i wasnt clear enough in my description. I dont want to have multiple section open at the same time only one but my code does that and i would like to modify it the way so it will only have one section open at the time, does that make sense?

Comment: If you only want one section open at a time why do you have multiple accordions?

Comment: here is code which i'm using http://testtwo.fsdegrees.com/accordions.html

Comment: you don't seem to be using the jquery ui accordion plugin. Is there any reason for that? http://jsfiddle.net/6jbuX/ for a UI.Accordion Plugin example

Comment: yes you right i will use that instead, Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(".accordion h3").click(function(){
    $('.accordion h3').each(function () {
      $(this).next("div").slideUp('slow');
    }
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("fast")
    .siblings("div:visible").slideDown("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="accordion">
<h3 class="accordion-title">Title</h3>
<div class="accordion-content">text</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.accordion-title').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children('.accordion-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".title_div").click(function(){
        $('.content_div').slideUp();
        if($(this).next().is(":visible")){
            $(this).next().slideUp();    
        }else{
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    });
```

```css
.title_div{ display:block; padding:10px 20px; border:1px solid #ddd;}

.content_div{ display:none; padding:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">    
  <div class="title_div">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="content_div">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since th
  </div>
  <div class="title_div">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="content_div">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since th
  </div>
  <div class="title_div">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="content_div">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since th
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo here](http://livetheme.in/Example/accordion)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple accordion (without accordion containers):

https://jsfiddle.net/iocron/mu4jg67n/3/

```js
$(".acc-content").hide();
$(".acc-toggler").on("click",function(e){
 var accContent = $(this).next(".acc-content");
  
 $(".acc-content").not(accContent).slideUp();
 accContent.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body,* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { line-height:1; }

.acc-toggler { padding:10px 12px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; background:#ddd; cursor:pointer; }
.acc-content { padding:10px 12px; background:#eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="acc-toggler">Accordion 1</h3>
  <div class="acc-content">Text Content 1</div>
  <h3 class="acc-toggler">Accordion 2</h3>
  <div class="acc-content">Text Content 2</div>
  <h3 class="acc-toggler">Accordion 3</h3>
  <div class="acc-content">Text Content 3</div>
</div>
```