# How to make jQuery Accordion scroll up instead of scroll up & to the left?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the jQuery Accordion and this seems to scroll up & to the left by default. The client has decided that they would like it to scroll up only, but I don't know what I need to change, of if there's something I need to call.

I'm using an extended version of the accordion, as described here: [Looking for a JQuery plug-in similar to Accordian, but that allows multiple sections open at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628006/looking-for-a-jquery-plug-in-similar-to-accordian-but-that-allows-multiple-secti/1639780#1639780)

Has somebody dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0):

If this is off the standard jQuery UI Accordian check to see if this property http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-animated makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got my accordion to always be fixed to the bottom and slide upward:

```
#accordion {
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```