# How can I modify they behaviour of this jQuery Accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using a slightly extended jQuery accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/AuJvc/

I've modified the accordion to allow multiple panels to be open at once, as outlined here: [Looking for a JQuery plug-in similar to Accordian, but that allows multiple sections open at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628006/looking-for-a-jquery-plug-in-similar-to-accordian-but-that-allows-multiple-secti/1639780#1639780)

If you check the jsfiddle example, you can see that when you click the title (Charges & Fees), the accordion scrolls up & to the left. How can I change this so that it just goes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.toggle("slow");
```

To

```
.slideToggle("slow");
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AuJvc/1/