# How to expand first 2 elements initially in jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a list of sections to show in jQuery UI Accordion.

```
    Section 1
    Section 2
    Section 3
    Section 4
    Section 5
```

Let me know how can I expand first 2 sections initially from code.

```
    Section 1(-)

    Section 2(-)

    Section 3(+)
    Section 4(+)
    Section 5(+)
```

Currently I can only expand one element with the following code.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-active

Comment: Well, i think the purpose of an accordion is to show only one at a time. On the [Accordion page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) you can read: **NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out [Accordion multiple sections open at once](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-multiple-sections-open-at-once)

Or this [extend the JQuery Accordion plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628006/looking-for-a-jquery-plug-in-similar-to-accordian-but-that-allows-multiple-sect/1639780#1639780)

Comment: Thanks Greg and all. jQuery plugin from @anasnakawa works for me . http://anasnakawa.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/jquery-ui-multi-open-accordion/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI Accordion does not let you have more than one section open:

> NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion
>
> An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are looking for a widget that allows more than one content panel to be open, don't use this. Usually it can be written with a few lines of jQuery instead, something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
         $(this).next().toggle();
         return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

Taken from http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion