# jquery ui accordion modifications

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

Usually in an accordion if I expand one item under one header,
the items under other header collapse automatically.
I don’t need this behavior .
I just need to expand one header only when we click on the same header, and need to collapse only when we click on the item second time.

How can I achieve this

Comment: not proper usage, try using `$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });` which will allow collapsing the active section, still only one section is open at any time

Answer (score 0):

This is not proper design for accordion use. However, you can find what you are looking for [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628006/looking-for-a-jquery-plug-in-similar-to-accordian-but-that-allows-multiple-sect)