# jQuery multiple hide and show panels

Tags: jquery, html, hide, toggle, show

The idea is to have a filter on the right similar to this one: - 
[Filter toggle example](http://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/leeds?room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home/apt&room_types%5B%5D=Private%20room&room_types%5B%5D=Shared%20room&price_min=111&price_max=200)

So basically i want to be able to have multiple expanded and collapsed divs like the example. The plugins i have found only allow for one div to be expanded at any given time.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: The only difference between the plugins you've found and the effect you linked to is the latter does not, on click, explicitly close any siblings (i.e. to allow only one open at a time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), but instead of having on accordion with multiple section you can create multiple accordions with one section.

Not sure what plugin you are using, but maybe you can use the same trick.

Or write your own...

```
<div class="panel collapsed">
    <h2 class="header">header1</h2>
    <div class="content">This is content</div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <h2 class="header">header2</h2>
    <div class="content">This is content</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The CSS...

```
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: silver;
    width: 200px;
}
.panel .header {
}
.panel.collapsed .content {
    display: none;
}
```

​
And the JavaScript (using jQuery)... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRCFa/2/) here

```
$(".panel .header").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("collapsed")
})
```

​
Or if you like fading... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRCFa/3/) here

```
​$(".panel .header").click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle();
})
```

​

Comment: this is more or less what im after, but i kind of need some divs expanded showing the content and some of them need to be clicked to display the content. Then when a user wants to expand/collapse each div they can do so.. possible with a +/- icon next to it. Similar to that of the demo in the link i attached, how they have different variations of the divs expand and collapse? cheers

Comment: @PaulBullock I changed the code so you can have certain panels expanded or collapsed when the page opens. Just add the class 'collapsed' to the content you want to hide initially. Adding a plus/minus can be done pretty easy with css for example. (Even made the code even simpler! One line in the click handler.)

Comment: awesome! Thank you!! Is it possible to put effects on that like slide up and down or fade also?

Comment: @PaulBullock Updated my answer and added fading support! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can show and hide multiple panels with this struckture;

[here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gWcFD/8/)

jQuery

```
$('.content').slideUp(1000);

$('.panel').click(function() {//open
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id');//takes id from clicked ele
   $('#'+takeID+'C').slideDown(1000);//show's clicked ele's id macthed div = 1second
});
$('span').click(function() {//close
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id').replace('Close','');//strip close from id = 1second
    $('#'+takeID+'C').slideUp(1000);//hide clicked close button's panel
});​
```

html:

```
<div class="panel" id="panel1">panel1</div>
<div id="panel1C">content1
  <span id="panel1Close">X</span>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="panel2">panel2</div>
<div id="panel2C">content2
  <span id="panel2Close">X</span>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="panel3">panel3</div>
<div id="panel3C">content3
  <span id="panel3Close">X</span>
</div>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628006/looking-for-a-jquery-plug-in-similar-to-accordian-but-that-allows-multiple-sect).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

Comment: @Bart Riemens this is more or less what im after, but i kind of need some divs expanded showing the content and some of them need to be clicked to display the content. Then when a user wants to expand/collapse each div they can do so.. possible with a +/- icon next to it. Similar to that of the demo in the link i attached, how they have different variations of the divs expand and collapse? cheers