# Animating height of a div to its original height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have come across a site https://nationalskillsregistry.com/pos-details-register.htm where i find the smooth height animations when clicked on Links (Ex. Ahmedabad). I guess this is not `slideUp()` function of jquery. I have searched many websites but did not find a way to animate height of a block to `0px` and then back to its original height. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: `slideUp` and `slideDown` are exactly what is used for that type of interaction.

Comment: @DA. yea but when we use `slideUp` and `slideDown` we observe that there is a movement of inner elements. But in the link i've mentioned the animation of the height is perfect.

Comment: that's usually due to padding and margin issues on the nested elements. One way around that is to cache the height of the rendered div (such as storing it as a `.data()` element. Then you can animate to that specific height.

Comment: I suggest you show us an example of what you have, and the inner movement problem, and then we can help debug that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website seems to use jQuery [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), although in a roundabout way.

From the page source:

```
<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('ahmedabad')">Ahmedabad</a>
```

If you check `animatedcollapse.js`, you will see the `toggle()` function:

```
toggle:function(divid){ //public method
    if (typeof divid=="object")
        divid=divid[0]
    this.showhide(divid, "toggle")
}
```

The `toggle()` function uses `showhide()`:

```
showhide:function(divid, action){
    var $divref=this.divholders[divid].$divref //reference collapsible DIV
    if (this.divholders[divid] && $divref.length==1){ //if DIV exists
        var targetgroup=this.divgroups[$divref.attr('groupname')] //find out which group DIV belongs to (if any)
        if ($divref.attr('groupname') && targetgroup.count>1 && (action=="show" || action=="toggle" && $divref.css('display')=='none')){ //If current DIV belongs to a group
            if (targetgroup.lastactivedivid && targetgroup.lastactivedivid!=divid) //if last active DIV is set
                this.slideengine(targetgroup.lastactivedivid, 'hide') //hide last active DIV within group first
                this.slideengine(divid, 'show')
            targetgroup.lastactivedivid=divid //remember last active DIV
        }
        else{
            this.slideengine(divid, action)
        }
    }
}
```

`showhide()` in turn uses `slideengine()`:

```
slideengine:function(divid, action){
    var $divref=this.divholders[divid].$divref
    if (this.divholders[divid] && $divref.length==1){ //if this DIV exists
        var animateSetting={height: action}
        if ($divref.attr('fade'))
            animateSetting.opacity=action
        $divref.animate(animateSetting, $divref.attr('speed')? parseInt($divref.attr('speed')) : 500)
        return false
    }
}
```

We can see that `$divref` from `slideengine()` is actually a jQuery object from the following line in `init()`:

```
this.$divref=$('#'+this.id)
```

Thus, we can conclude that the website uses jQuery `animate()`:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Normally it would not be this easy to find out what exactly is going on, as websites do not tend to provide non-minified and commented versions of its code...

Note: If I am not supposed to post the above code, then someone please let me know.

**Edit:**

As mentioned by others, you can use jQuery UI's [`accordion`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). Another option would be to use jQuery's [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

Comment: Great job! I don't think anyone would ask you to hide this code away, since it is the webmaster's job to make sure his scripts are secured (in a way). Have you ever thought becoming a website analyst/inspector?

Comment: Thanks @Ghillied, and no I have not really thought about it. Aside from lacking (I think) the right expertise and skillset, I would much rather be writing code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check accordion in jQuery UI ?

Since you need more than one accordion open at a time try this

**Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/apSsR/8/**

If that doesnt help

[Looking for a JQuery plug-in similar to Accordian, but that allows multiple sections open at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628006/looking-for-a-jquery-plug-in-similar-to-accordian-but-that-allows-multiple-sect)

Comment: There is a note saying that
NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion,

An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time.

But in the mentioned link we could see multiple sections at a time.
I guess accordian may not do the job with the type of animation achieved in the mentioned website.